# Pass value from one file(encrypted) to yaml with yaml inside

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I've got a yaml file with config for helm charts, and there is a section that looks like this:

```
master:
  enabled: true
  configScripts:
    config: | 
      password: xxx
```

I wanted to subtitute the password with the known way `{{ .Values.secrets.password }}` but since it's yaml in yaml I cannot - or can I? does anyone know a way, preferably it would be kept in separate file that is encrypted on git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can. Just deal with the `config` (could be YAML, JSON, etc.) as a string.

```yaml
master:
  enabled: true
  configScripts:
    config: {{- printf "password: %s" (printf "%s" .Values.secrets.password | b64enc) }}
```

Comment: hmm the config itself has over 300 lines in the actual values file, I guess it could be exported to secondary file in full, I'll try to test it but might not work